# how to import vue component into laravevel app.js file?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

I am trying to import vue into laravel appjs file but am seeing no result.
My component is called Dash.vue and its located in 'resources\js\components'

The code below is what i have tried

```
import Dash from 'resources\js\components';
    new Vue({

      components: {
       "Dash": YourComponent

    });
```

Comment: in blade you want to show ?

Comment: yes sir. im new to coding ad especially to vue.

Comment: Your path isn't right. Try `./components/Dash.vue`

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
 import Dash from './resources/js/components/Dash';
     new Vue({

       components: {
        Dash

      });
```

Comment: ok and how can i test if it works. how do i display it in blade view file? do i have to include it like normal js file?

Comment: I didn't quite understand the question... if you want to view it and see if it works, try writing something into the template of the `Dash` component. If you see it then it works